# Can a computer peripheral (keyboard) be more sophisticated than meets the eye and steal data?

Tags: hardware, usb, keyboard

There are lots of mechanical keyboards out on the market now. When you buy one from a known name it's likely there's nothing nefarious going on. But no name peripherals have flooded the market. Cheap keyboards that offer many features at a much cheaper price.

It seems reasonable to be suspicious here. I know keyboards act as a HID to the computer, but can a usb keyboard do more? Could the controller on the keyboard capture sensitive data and send it to the bad guys? passwords, secrets, messages, etc.

I know keyloggers are a thing but they seldom are the keyboard themselves.

is this possible?

Comment: There are many keyboard with full processors on them with programmable keys, screens, etc. So, ... yes ... they can be more...